# Trying to find laplace transform $x(s)$ that satisfies $x'(t)=x(t)-t$?

Tags: laplace-transform

Taking the Laplace transform of the equation
$$x'(t)=x(t)-t,$$
we get
$$sx(s)-x(0)=x(s)-\frac{1}{s^2},$$
right? So if $x(0)=1$, don't you get
$$x(s)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{s^2}}{s-1}?$$
When I take the inverse laplace of this I get 2pi*i, how do I know this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{1-\frac{1}{s^2}}{s-1}=\frac{s^2-1}{s^2(s-1)}=\frac{s+1}{s^2}=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2}.
$$

How did you get zero for the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: Okay now I get 2*pi*i for the inverse, but how does that work with the original equation x'(t) = x(t) - t?

Comment: @Marcus How do you get this particular inverse? The answer is $1+t$ as you can simply check.

Comment: I got this, residue's not the way to go!

Comment: Good for you :) Considering your deleted comment -- you should take a small break from math.

Comment: By the way, could you tell me why the residue way doesn't work?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question. The simplest answer is "because it is not the way to find the inverse Laplace transform". A better answer is "Look at the formula which you use to find the inverse Laplace transform and look at the integrals you can evaluate by using the residues".